# Formatting currency using numberFormatter

Tags: php, number-formatting

I ran into some problems using the php NumberFormatter class. I want rounded digits to be displayed without any decimals, and digits which has decimals to be rounded with 2 decimals. i.e.

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('nl', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$fmt->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
$fmt->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);

var_dump($fmt->formatCurrency(15.15, 'EUR')); //Outputs € 15,15
var_dump($fmt->formatCurrency(15, 'EUR')); //Outputs € 15,00
```

As you can see the last dump is outputting `15,00` but I'm expecting `15` here.
Whenever I use the "full" locale `nl_NL` instead of `nl` the formatter behaves as expected, but I'm unable to use that because I only have the language available in my locale.

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('nl_NL', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$fmt->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
$fmt->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);

var_dump($fmt->formatCurrency(15.15, 'EUR')); //Outputs € 15,15
var_dump($fmt->formatCurrency(15, 'EUR')); //Output € 15
```

This seems like a bug in the NumberFormatter but I really have no clue how to fix it or figure out some other workaround. I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug. If that is indeed the case, the fix is not to use the NumberFormatter, but create your own. For a quick fix, you could query the formatted currency for ,00 at the end of the string, and simply strip it off if true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Writing my own is not really an option as we have a website with many languages. I could implement a dirty fix like that if nobody else has a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty fix:

```
$formattedCurrency = preg_replace('/,00$/', '', $fmt->formatCurrency(15, 'EUR'));
```

Comment: Thanks. It should be `/[,\.]00$/` btw because in english they are using dots. 15.00

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `MAX_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS` attribute:

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('nl', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$fmt->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS, 7);

var_dump($fmt->formatCurrency(15.15, 'EUR')); // Outputs € 15,15
var_dump($fmt->formatCurrency(15, 'EUR'));    // Outputs € 15
```

Comment: I don’t know why the ‘dirty fix’ is marked as the correct asnswer here, this one worked for me, but I set `MAX_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS` to `100`.